# If an event is mutually exclusive find $P(A' \cap B')$

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

So the question says that you have A and B event they are mutually exclusive so find 
$P(A' \cap B')$ I have solved it by :

$$P((A \cup B)') = 1 - P(A \cup B) $$

But what is the effect of being mutually exclusive? And become $0$ so do I treat her like $P(A \text{ and } B)$ or what?

Answer (score 1):

mutually exclusive means $P(A \cap B)= 0$.

Hence

\begin{align}P(A' \cap B')&=P((A \cup B)')\\&=1-P(A \cup B)\\&=1-P(A)-P(B)+P(A\cap B)\\
&= 1-P(A)-P(B) \end{align}

Comment: So the mutually exclusive doesn't effect the complement in this case?

Comment: Is your concern $P(A' \cap B')$ can be positive?

Comment: No I think it's can be zero

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding you, can you clarify?

Comment: Cuz it's mutually exclusive so P( A and B) = 0 then my brain told me that P(A' and B') would be 0 too

Comment: draw a venn diagram where circle $A$ and circle $B$ do not overlap. sketch the region of $A'$ and also the region of $B'$, you can see that they could overlap.

Comment: Yes how didn't I think about that!! Thank you very much ♥️♥️♥️♥️♥️